# JSON loop and markers on google maps, displayed just one

Tags: json, google-maps-api-3

Hi I have this loop on a JSON array which contains multiple markers. I'm not sure why but I can display just one marker. Here is the code

```
function plotMarkers(northEastLat,northEastLong,southWestLat,southWestLong){  

jQuery.ajax({
    url: 'geocoder.php',
    dataType:'json',
    type: "POST",
    data: {
        nelat: northEastLat,
        nelong: northEastLong,
        swlat: southWestLat,
        swlong: southWestLong
    },
}).done(function(brArray) {

   if (brArray == undefined || brArray == null || brArray.length == 0){
        //no elements around you

    } else {

        $(jQuery.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(brArray))).each(function() {  

            var NAME = this.name;
            var LATITUDE = this.latitude;
            var LONGIT = this.longit;
            var ADDRESS = this.address;
            var NAMEELEMENT = this.nameelement;

            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: NAME + '<br>' + NAMEELEMENT  + '<br>' + ADDRESS
            });

            var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(LATITUDE, LONGIT); 
            // Creating a marker and putting it on the map
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: latLng,
                map: map,
                icon: 'img/marker.png',
                title: NAME + ' - ' + NAMEELEMENT
            });

            marker.setMap(map);
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                infowindow.open(map,marker);
            });
        });         

    }
});
```

plotMarkers() is called in the function which initializes the map

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', function() {
 plotMarkers(map.getBounds().getNorthEast().lat(), map.getBounds().getNorthEast().lng(), map.getBounds().getSouthWest().lat(), map.getBounds().getSouthWest().lng());  
});
```

Comment: Can you post more of your code or provide a live example to work with?  And why are you calling `JSON.stringify` just to `jQuery.parseJSON` it?

Comment: I was using JSON.stringify just to parse it? I put more code, I'm trying this function locally

Comment: Can you post the JSON? There is nothing inside the code that would explain this behaviour.

Comment: I've just realized that the JSON array contains just one element and not two as expected. I tested the while loop in the file geocoder.php file and also the query on the db and both gave me as a result two elements. The object that I printed using console.dir(brArray) gave me this result: `Object
address: "595 Burrard Street"
latitude: "49.285822459"
longit: "-123.119431973"
name: "Post office"
nameelement: "Element test"`

Comment: Ok guys I solved the problem, the main problem was in the while loop in the php file. The loop that generat the array. So the problem wasn't related to the markers.